# What does mean ''I'm to do''

Tags: future-tense

As i mean what does mean ''I'm to do or you are to take''? this is a future event but i couldn't get it. What's difference I'll do and I'm gonna do? Also can you give me example about this?  Be + verb form

Comment: Have a look at the "Auxiliary Verb" definition 3 of *be* in [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/be). (You'll need to scroll down past the first block of definitions, which refer to *be* as a *verb*.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a future. The link provided by @Lawrence states that it is "Used to indicate something that is due or destined to happen," but I find that a little confusing. More specifically, I would say your examples are from subpart 3.1, "Used to express obligation or necessity."

Example: "You are to clean your room" - It seems unlikely (especially if said from parent to teenager) that it is expressing something that is destined to happen! More likely, the parent is telling the child, "I want you to clean your room."

Same with "take": "You are to take all your belongings." This is not a prediction but a command.

By the way, I should say that these all sound a bit stilted to me. You'd most likely find these more commonly in writing than in speaking.